# Nested JSON on WireMock Response

Tags: json, escaping, wiremock, stubbing, wiremock-standalone

Is there any way to dynamically include JSON from the request body in the response?

**Input Request**

```json
{
   "id":"1234",
   "message":"{\"key\":\"value\"}"
}
```

**Expected Output**

```json
{
  "status":"CREATED",
  "id":"1234",
  "message":"{\"key\":\"value\"}"
}
```

The **message** and **id** fields are dynamic and need to be picked from the request.

I have tried the below mapping to dynamically load the response from the request but `\"` inside message json is converted to `&quot;`

```json
{
  "request": {
    "method": "POST",
    "urlPath": "/test"
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "transformers": [
      "response-template"
    ],
    "jsonBody": {
      "status": "CREATED",
      "id": "{{jsonPath request.body '$.id'}}",
      "message": "{{jsonPath request.body '$.message'}}"
    }
  }
}
```

This returns message as `{&quot;key&quot;:&quot;value&quot;}`.

Even, I have tried changing the mapping to `{{{jsonPath request.body '$.message'}}}`. But this messes up the whole response json and message value is being returned as `"{"key":"value"}"` without escape characters.

I'm looking for suggestions to map message dynamically. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you happen to solve this? I have encountered similar issue and cannot figure it out